# How to make docker service available at local network

Tags: spring-boot, docker

I am new to `docker` and i made my `API` available on host as follows:

`sudo docker run -p 7777:8085 phillalexakis/myfirstapi:01` and my **Spring Boot API** starts

[image]

Then i get my container's id and i run  `sudo docker inspect my_containter_id` .

[image]

The address of the running app is `172.17.0.2` which means it can be accessed at `172.17.02:7777` from host and it works

Although when I'm visiting `172.17.02:7777` from another local machine  I'm unable to connect to it (i also tried `8085` port )

Based on [this documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) i need to specify some options in `daemon.json` but i don't know how. Is this enough to make it available on my local network?

Comment: Once you are exposing your container with -p 7777:8085, you can access your host from another in same lan using your local ip:7777, like 192.168.10.2:777 supposing that you local ip is 192.168.10.2. This address 172.17.0.2 is for docker internal address.

Comment: based on `ip addr` on my `wlo1`  the `inet` address is `192.168.2.9/24` but i can't access it at `192.168.2.9:7777` neither at `192.168.2.9:8085` from another local machine

Comment: what about the https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/#user-defined-networks user defined networks?

Comment: User-defined network is useful when you want communicate 02 or more containers without expose it. I think it is not your case. Do you have some firewall rules on your host that can block access?

Answer (score 0):

You start your container with a `docker run -p` option

```
docker run -p 7777:8085 ...
```

The container can be accessed via the host’s DNS name or IP address, and the first port number 7777.

(This is the same as any service you run on your host.  If you directly run, say, an nginx server, with or without Docker, it’s visible on some port on the host’s IP address.)

The Docker-internal IP address cannot be reached from other hosts, and looking it up isn’t useful.  It’s an implementation detail that you can almost always ignore.

Comment: so my host's `IP` is `192.168.2.9` shouldn't i be able to access it at `192.168.2.9:7777` from a local machine?